# Pass parameter value to another controller using session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there anyway I can pass the value of a parameter to another action such as session? For example in order for a user to go to the next page and so on they have to enter in an access code. So if they try to change the url to try to skip the entering in the access code they will be redirected. So what i am trying to accomplish is keeping the access code in session

```
def welcome_access
    @code = params[:access_code] == ENV['ACCESS_CODE']
    session[:passed_parameter] = @code
    if @code
        redirect_to users_welcome_path
      else
        flash[:alert] =  "Incorrect access code"
        redirect_to  request.referer
    end

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
    end
  end

  def welcome_submit
    @code = session[:passed_parameter]
    @welcome_code = @code
      if @welcome_code
        if params[:user_type] == "patient"  
          redirect_to new_patient_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "surrogate" 
          redirect_to surrogate_patients_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "surrogate"
          redirect_to new_patient_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "provider"
          redirect_to new_provider_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "facilitator"
          redirect_to new_facilitator_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "ancillary"
          redirect_to new_ancillary_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "administrator"
          redirect_to new_administrator_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "emergency"
          redirect_to new_emergency_path
        elsif params[:user_type] == "paramedic"
          redirect_to new_paramedic_path
        end
      else
      redirect_to request.referer
    end
  end
```

here is my modal code

```
<div class="modal-box">
    <%= form_tag users_welcome_access_path, method: :post do %>
        <div class="close">x</div>
        <div class="title">Access Code</div>
        <div id="modal-container" class="container sm-height">
             <div class="buttons">
                  <div class="header">
                    <%= label :access_code, "Enter correct access code to continue registration"%>
                    <%= text_field_tag :access_code %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="header" style="margin-top: 15px">
                    <%= submit_tag 'Continue', class: "btn-submit" %>
                  <button class="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
                 <div class="push"></div>
                     </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working here?

Comment: This line `@code = params[:access_code] == ENV['ACCESS_CODE']` will just assign `true` (strings match) or `false` (strings do not match) to `@code`. This is very likely not what you want.

Comment: @maxpleaner well whats going is on my home page localhost:3000 a user is prompt to enter an access code to move on to the sign up page localhost:3000/users/user.welcome which works fine when a user enters in the right access code it will redirect to that page. BUT if you just go to the url and change it to localhost:000/users/user.welcome it will allow the user to go to that page without entering the access code.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, the front end is requesting welcome_submit directly but @code is nil so its redirecting to request referrer. Is that right? You can use a breakpoint so see what the flow of the code is

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do the authorization/redirection with a [before filter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). These filters let you define methods that should be called before every controller method. Authentication tools typically leverage these pretty heavily, as it lets you check whether a user is authenticated before you get to the meat of your method.

For example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate!

  # authenticate! is automatically called before this method
  def welcome_access
    # user is already authenticated at this point, or else was redirected to request.referer
    respond_to do |format|
      # ...
    end
  end

  # authenticate! is automatically called before this method
  def welcome_submit
    # user is already authenticated at this point, or else was redirected to request.referer
    case params[:user_type]
    when "patient" then redirect_to new_patient_path
    # more redirects here...
    when "paramedic" then redirect_to new_paramedic_path
    end
  end

  private

  def authenticate!
    session[:passed_parameter] = params[:access_code] if params[:access_code].present?
    if !correct_code?
      flash[:alert] =  "Incorrect access code"
      redirect_to request.referer
    end
  end

  def correct_code?
    session[:passed_parameter] == ENV['ACCESS_CODE']
  end
end
```

A few other notes/suggestions:

- Consider using `case`/`when` instead of a long `if`-`elsif` chain. See my example.
- The respond_to in welcome_access is never getting hit because you'll always be redirected first. Either have welcome access redirect to a different page, or render html.
- Instead of `redirect_to request.referer`, prefer [`redirect_back`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)
- You might want to look into some gems that handle authentication for you. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a powerful general purpose gem for this. People rarely roll their own auth in practice, (unless, say, they're just doing it to learn) and learning to use gems in your project is a good skill to have in its own right. Certainly it's more secure.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow thanks! I am actually using devise for authentication. What I am doing is in order to sign up for a user account they have to enter an access code to continue throughout the registration process. I have multiple steps for registration and i want the user to enter an access code for security purposes. So everything works perfect now! However, my modal that prompt the user to enter in the access code will not pop up now. but all the redirects works if the access code is not in session. Here is my modal code above

Comment: What action renders the modal?

Comment: If the page that renders the modal is coming from the same controller, then the before_filter might be preventing that page from rendering at all. Like a sort of catch-22: You need to first be authenticated before you can get to the authentication modal that allows you to authenticate... If this is what's happening, just change the before action to `before_action :authenticate!, except: :whatever_the_action_is_that_renders_the_modal`. This is mentioned in the before_action [doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), but it doesn't give an example.